# Caching with API Gateway and multiple URL Query String Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to cache the response of my API based on multiple query string parameters, but once I hit the server once, the other response will get the same content with different query string parameters.[image]

Comment: are you redeploying to your stage after you update the settings?

Comment: @JDD What do you mean ? I'm not deploying yet, I would like to have something working first

Comment: how are you testing the changes to your API?

Comment: I call the endpoint